# Are explicit imports able to reduce compiled file size?

Tags: haskell

I will ask about *usefulness*. It's about the impact on the size of the compiled executable/library. Not about code maintainability or readability.

## Importing specific module

Is it useful to import the only used module from a package instead of importing the main module (which imports itself the submodules).

For example, with the `Foreign` module (which contains only an import list):

```
import Foreign.Storable
```

instead of:

```
import Foreign
```

## Explicitly importing functions/types

Is it useful to import just the used function/types instead of importing the whole module ?

For example:

```
import Foreign.ForeignPtr (ForeignPtr, mallocForeignPtr, withForeignPtr)
```

instead of:

```
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling a simple application in two different ways and seeing if you get a difference? My suspicion is that you’ll get bigger files if you compile without optimisation and the same size with optimisation. But it may be that you’d need LTO. I don’t think you’ll get a difference importing functions explicitly versus a module at a time

Comment: This is not a characteristic of Haskell code; it's a characteristic of linking. Firstly, if you link dynamically, none of this will make a difference so I assume you're talking about static linking. In your first case, it only has an affect if [`split-objs`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--split-objs) is enabled; otherwise, the entire library is linked. In the second case, it will never make a difference; importing even no names (!) from a module requires linking in the entire module (or the entire package without `split-objs` enabled).

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for your answer ! Make it a real answer and I will validate it.

Comment: @user2407038 What about [split-sections](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--split-sections) ? The documentation says it is more efficient than `split-objs`.

Comment: @user2407038, what if no names or class instances are used (in an executable) or re-exported (in a library)? Someone could want to import a module just for type families and types without strict fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the modules are compiled as an object file, then no, not even in theory.  Functions that can’t be imported can still be used internally, and you could load the module up in `GHCI` and test the unexported internal functions.

If you’re linking statically or using specific instances of a generic function, then in theory the compiler should be able to analyze which pieces of the library are unreachable from this specific program, and as a whole-program optimization, pare them out of the executable.  (For example, if the only lists your program uses are lists of `Int`, maybe the compiler only compiles the partially-specialized `[Int]` versions of generic functions, and only the ones you use.)  However, it should be able to do the same static analysis as a whole-program optimization no matter how you declare your imports and exports.

When compiling a dynamic library, it could in theory exclude a code path or piece of data that static analysis proves can never be reached, directly or indirectly, by any possible call through the exported interface.  If so, a compiler could use the export list to prove that some identifier in the library is completely useless and leave it out of the compiled library.

If you’re asking what some specific compiler, such as GHC 8, does, I don’t know.  You’d have to test it and see.

The main benefit of specifically listing your exports and imports is that you’ll never run into trouble, years later, when a second module declares an identifier you’re already using.  This has happened to me before, and now I’m a lot more careful.